# Oracle: not group by expression error

Tags: oracle

```
select case when x.a in (select y.c from join2) then x.a end, x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c 
from join1 x, join2 y, join3 z where x.a = z.a 
group by x.a, x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c order by x.c;
```

While running this query I am getting `error ORA-00979` a group by expression. I already tried by removing x.a from group by but still not working. Can any body help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have this expression in your `GROUP BY` clause instead of `x.a`:

```
case when x.a in (select y.c from join2) then x.a end
```

So putting it all together:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x.a IN ( SELECT y.c FROM join2) THEN x.a END
     , x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c
  FROM join1 x, join2 y, join3 z
 WHERE x.a = z.a
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN x.a IN ( SELECT y.c FROM join2) THEN x.a END
     , x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c
 ORDER BY x.c;
```

I do have to point out, however, that you're doing a cartesian join between `x` and `y` and it's not completely clear why you're using `GROUP BY` since there are no aggregates.

Comment: thanx david  but i need one more help. I like to use above query same as, select x.a , x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c
  FROM join1 x, join2 y, join3 z
 WHERE x.a=y.c and x.a = z.a
 GROUP BY x.a, x.b, x.c, y.a, z.c
 ORDER BY x.c;  Can You help me on this?

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with it; if you need help I'd suggest asking a new question.